# Gmail cuts EPS files

Tags: gmail, eps

I have a peculiar problem - upon sending .eps files on Gmail, they "get cut", on their way. By "get cut" I mean that the recipient receives a valid .eps file which contains only a fraction of the original image.

However, using Dropbox or Google Drive, they remain intact.

Comment: Many EPS files contain embedded preview images. If you recipient does not have a propper application to view EPS he might be only viewing the preview image (e.g., irfanview can only show the eps preview). gmail also provides previews for many files, but again the preview is rather poor compared to the original file. Just do an MD5 or SHA1 checksum before sending the file and compare it with the recieved file.

Comment: @masgo indeed when I download my own file, it seems intact. Do you think I should close the question if the "fault" is so plain?

Comment: if the error is just the gmail preview: yes, close the question. the gmail preview is very limited ... it produces all kinds of errors with any complex filetype like (docx, pdf, eps, svg, psd, ...)

Comment: @masgo At least in my gmail's "inbox" there isn't any preview. I suspect that it is a problem on my recipient's client eps viewer, but I'm not sure.